# Retain whitespace between tags within mixed-content tags

Tags: sql, oracle

We are using XML DB in Oracle Database 12c. We have a problem retaining whitespaces between tags. Note that we have already registered our schema in the database that defines which tags are mixed-content type. I think we have done this properly since inserting XMLs not conforming to the schema will raise an exception.

For example:

```
with
input as (
  select xmltype(
     '<content> <inline>hello</inline>  <inline>world</inline> </content>') 
  as xml_doc
  from dual)
select xmlserialize(document xml_doc no indent)
  from input
```

*Note that the above is an example only, we properly set `xmlns` and other root attributes properly to refer to registered schemas.*

Will output:

```
'<content><inline>hello</inline><inline>world</inline></content>'
```

Whereas we expected the output to be:

```
'<content> <inline>hello</inline>  <inline>world</inline> </content>'
```

Is this an Oracle bug or are we doing something wrong? Oracle should not remove the whitespaces between `<inline>` since their parent `<content>` is of mixed content-type.

Edit:

- "no indent" in xmlserialize is used so that no additional whitespace is introduced in the XML. And besides, any XML operation (XQuery) results to removal of whitespaces between tags.
- xml:space="preserve" is not an option since XML may be indented. Indentation whitespaces should not be preserved.

Answer (score 1):

Removing `no indent` gives the expected output in `oracle 11g` like below

```
with
input as (
  select xmltype(
     '<content> <inline>hello</inline>  <inline>world</inline> </content>') 
  as xml_doc
  from dual)
select xmlserialize(document xml_doc )
  from input
```

I hope this will work in `oracle 12c` also

Comment: "no indent" in xmlserialize is used so that no additional whitespace is introduced in the XML. And besides, any XML operation (XQuery) results to removal of whitespaces between tags.